# Identify species of snake in India

Tags: species-identification, snake

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZrNC.jpg)

[image: CLose image]
[image: Large image]

Is this snake poisonous, found wrapped around a tree in middle of hot summer of 40 degrees celcius, in himachal, Northern INDIA, Himalayan foothills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [bronzeback tree snake](https://www.inaturalist.org/guide_taxa/1331752), which is a common species of tree snake in India. It is a slender snake with characteristic bronze body and a pale stripe down the sides. It usually has a white spot on top of its head, which I think you can see in the second picture. It should also have blue inter-scale areas if you pull the scales apart.

It is non-venomous, but like all snakes may bite if attacked.